How to ease the computation of ${\partial^2 z \over \partial x \partial y}$ in this problem?
$f(u,v)$ is a function such that

its second derivatives exists and they are continuous

$z=z(x,y)$ is defined by the equation
$$
f(z-x, z-y)=1
$$
find ${\partial^2 z \over \partial x \partial y}$.
My method is to compute the first order partial derivatives from the both sides of the equation, and find out
$$
{\partial z \over \partial x}={f_1' \over f_1' + f_2'},{\partial z \over \partial y}={f_2' \over f_1' + f_2'}
$$
which implies
$$
z_{x}'+z_{y}'=1 \implies z_{xy}''+z_{yy}''=0 \implies z_{xy}''=-z_{yy}''
$$
The process of computing $z_{yy}''$ scared me, and it's too long and too tedious. Any method to easy the computation process?

Why not just re-differentiate wrt $x$ your equation $z'_y(f'_1+f'_2)-f'_2=0$?

@kurodamaria Why haven't you commented my answer to your previous question ?
